# Updating PHP version on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, php, ppa

I have PHP version 5.6.17 and I want to update it to 5.6.32. When I try to run `apt-get update` I get error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-
5.6/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-
5.6/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
```

I changed in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php5-5_6-trusty.list` from

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu
```

to

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu
```

and then there are no errors but still it does not update it. What should I do?

Output of `apt list --installed |grep php`:

```
libapache2-mod-php5/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php-pear/now 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14 all [installed,upgradable to: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.22]
php5/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 all [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-cgi/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-cli/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-common/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-curl/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-fpm/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-gd/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-json/now 1.3.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+3 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1.3.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+4]
php5-mcrypt/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-memcached/unknown,now 2.2.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed]
php5-mysql/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-readline/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
php5-sqlite/now 5.6.17+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567133/cannot-add-ppa-ppaondrej-php5-5-6

Comment: Does `apt-mark showhold` output something?

Comment: @Videonauth nope

Comment: Output of `apt list --installed | grep php` please. Not sure where 5.6.17 is coming from; the official Trusty repos have 5.5.9.

Comment: @fkraiem Here is output - https://pastebin.com/raw/46pp8dRf

Comment: Try to first remove all PHP packages, then install `php5.6` (not `php5`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ondrej Sury at some point changed the naming convention of PHP packages in his PPA; PHP 5.6 packages for Trusty now use the string `php5.6` instead of `php5`. This is why, for example, the package `php5` was not upgraded: the newer versions are in the package `php5.6`, which is a different package.

Thus in order to get the new version, one must remove all `php5` packages and install their `php5.6` counterparts. A list of all currently installed `php5` packages can be obtained with `apt list --installed | grep php5`.